# Adding decimal to percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, geometry

I've tried adding a `parseFloat` and `toFixed` to this, but to no avail. Anyone know why the percentage isn't using the decimal?

Here the example : http://jsfiddle.net/NyE2d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was rounding it to the nearest integer. Of course that won't show any decimal.

It works fine when you use `toFixed()` at the right spot:
http://jsfiddle.net/NyE2d/1/

Comment: Out of curiosity... where were you adding `toFixed()` so that it wasn't working?

Comment: Everywhere, except the html apparently. Embarrassing.